# call max() on a double in java

Tags: java

I have a programming assignment that requires me to get user inputs and store them in an array of doubles. I then have to print them all and then print the maximum value. I know that there are better ways to do this, but this is what I have.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class ch6p3
{
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[]args)
{
double numbers[] = new double[10];

System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[0] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[1] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[2] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[3] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[4] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[5] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[6] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[7] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[8] = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("enter a number");
numbers[9] = input.nextDouble();    
System.out.println("enter a number");
int sub = 0;

System.out.println("the values are: ");
double a = numbers[0];
double b = numbers[1];
double c = numbers[2];
double d = numbers[3];
double e = numbers[4];
double f = numbers[5];
double g = numbers[6];
double h = numbers[7];
double i = numbers[8];
double j = numbers[9];

do
{
System.out.print(numbers[sub] + ", ");
sub++;


}while(sub<10);
double maximum = max(max(max(max(max(max(max(max(max(a,b),c),d),e),f),g),h),i),j);
System.out.print("the maximum value is: " + maximum);
```

}

}

I know that calling max so many times is rather inefficient, but I have yet to figure out how to make a for loop for it. I'll do that next.

My question is: what is a double equivalent of Math.max() and how do you use it?

Comment: `Math.max` has a signature that accepts two doubles. That said, *please* use a `for` loop.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_max.htm

Comment: See my pseudocode below. There's no need to store the items in the array into seperate doubles eg. double a = numbers[0]. You can print them directly from the array, System.out.print(numbers[0]). Plus, use a for loop to determine the max value.

Comment: I would also put the input in a for loop, much more efficient/maintainable/readable. for(i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) { System.out.println("Enter a number:"); numbers[i] = input.nextDouble(); };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop like specified in the comments. Here's the pseudocode:

```
    DECLARE A DOUBLE TO HOLD THE MAX NUMBER
        FOR i=0 TO NUMBER OF ELEMENTS IN ARRAY
           IF THE ITH ELEMENT IS GREATER THAN THE CURRENT MAX NUMBER THEN SET THE CURRENT MAX TO THE ITH ELEMENT.
        END FOR
PRINT MAX NUM
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are probably one of the few people that tells the pseudocode rather than the actual code, so I know what I'm doing.

Comment: I prefer to use pseudocode, rather than give the answer. That allows you to learn the code better, rather than copy and paste. You'll get there just give it time.

Answer (score 2):

[java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class provides a [max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(double,%20double)) method to find maximum of two double inputs. Here is the signature:

```
public static double max(double a,
         double b)
```

Comment: Please do not just copy and paste something from the internet. I already saw that and it made me try to write a value return method. Notice I said TRY.

Comment: @trailrunnersquared Sorry, tried to help u. Wouldn't do that again.

Comment: Its fine. I didn't mean to sound so rude right there. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static double userMax(double[] array) {
    double maximum = array[0];

    for (double d: array) {
        maximum = Math.max(maximum, d);
    }

    return double;
}
```

Now after defining this function, you can call:

```
double toTheMax = userMax(numbers);
```

Comment: Be carefull, if all doubles are negative then 0 would be the (wrong) max. You can do `maximum = array[0]` or use Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Math.max()`. It works with doubles as well.